# If $f(g(x))$ $1-1$, then must$ f $ and $g$ be $1-1$?

Tags: functions

**My Question** is If $f(g(x))$ is $1-1$, then **must** f **and** g be $1-1$?

I know this is True, but should both f and g be $1-1$?

I remember having a vague idea that it is **enough for one** of $f$ or $g$ must be $1-1$, and there is no need for both of these to be $1-1 $for $f(g(x))$ to be $1-1$.

Comment: If $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, then what can you say about $f(g(x_1))$ and $f(g(x_2))$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That $f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2))$ ?

Comment: So if $g$ is not injective, then ____?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $f(g(x))$ is injective?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to figure out what you mean.  Let
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}\log x & \text{if }x>0; \\
44 & \text{if }x\leq 0
\end{cases} \\
g(x) &= e^x,\qquad x \in \mathbb R
\end{align*}
which of these is 1-1?  What is $f(g(x))$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I understood 1-1 as *bijective*.

**Answer:**

No, we only know that $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective. But it can be the case that $g$ is not surjective and $f$ not injective.

**Example:**

- $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$, $g(x):=x^2$
- $f:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$, $f(x):=\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: You know $f$ is surjective only if $f\circ g$  is surjective.

Comment: How do you deduce that $f$ is surjective given that $f\circ g$ is injective? I think 1-1 is an abbreviation of *injective*, though it would make sense for it to mean *bijective*.

Comment: @Bernard Because in the end it is $f$ which attains every value when you unfold the definition of $f\circ g$.